# applying promotion code instead of coupon in laravel/cashier

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

i am trying to use Promotion code instead of coupon code in laravel cashier/stripe official package but i couldn't find any help in there on how to apply promotion code instead of coupon on subscription as i know how to apply coupon but i want to apply promotion code, how can i do it.
below is my code for applying coupon when creating new subscription but i don't know how can i achieve it using promotion code:

```
$subscription = $user->newSubscription($plan->name, $selectedPlan);

            // Add the trial days if any
            if ($plan->trial_days) {
                $subscription = $subscription->trialDays($plan->trial_days);
            }

            // Add the coupon id if any
            if ($request->input('coupon_id')) {
                $subscription = $subscription->withCoupon($request->input('coupon_id'));
            }

            $subscription->create($paymentMethod->id, [
                'email' => $user->email
            ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add promotion code by using the `->withPromotionCode()` e.g.

```
if ($request->input('promotion_code_id')) {
    $subscription = $subscription->withPromotionCode($request->input('promotion_code_id'));
}
```

However, this function requires the promotion code ID instead of the code, and most likely you want your user to key in the code, not the ID. In such case, you can retrieve all active promotion codes and match the code.

```
if ($request->has('promotion_code')) {
    $stripeClient = new \Stripe\StripeClient(config('cashier.secret'));
    $result = $this->stripe->promotionCodes->all(
        ['code' => $request->get("promotion_code"), 'active' => true]
    );

    if($result->isEmpty()){
        // handle invalid promo code here
    }

    $promoCodeID = $result->first()->id;
    $subscription = $subscription->withPromotionCode($promoCodeID);
}
```